# Wordpress Contact Form I can submit to from my Mobile App with API?

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins, contact-form

I'm looking everywhere for a contact form plugin in Wordpress that would allow me the option to submit to it externally with an API endpoint. I want the client to be able to view submissions within the Wordpress dashboard which is why I'm opting for a plugin but unable to find one that allows me to use it outside of embedding it with a shortcode inside Wordpress itself.

Does a plugin like this exist? If not what are some recommendations for tackling this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom API endpoint.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

```
    function register_custom_route() {
        register_rest_route('gn/v1', '/contact', [
            'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback' => 'ajax_custom_',
        ]);
    }    
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_custom_route');


    function ajax_custom_function( $request ) {
       //get contact form value here and integrate with your contact form functionality
       $post = $request->get_params();       
   }
```

Above function will create endpoint like http://sitename.com/wp-json/gn/v1/contact